# Why does this work in Firefox but not IE?

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

```
           'display the left product image
           if intImagePos = 2 then
              response.write("<td class=""ProductImage"">" & vbcrlf)
              'show image
              if Len(objProduct.Image2) > 0 then
                 response.write("<a class=""thumbnail"" href=""javascript: void(0)"" onclick=""MM_openBrWindow('images/festool/KAPEXKS120-571287/KAPEXKS120-571287-Gallery/','scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=840,height=580')""><img src=" & objProduct.Image1 & " border=""0""><br>See gallery of this product</a>")
              else
                 response.write("<p>No Picture Available</p>")
              end if
              response.write("</td>")
           end if
```

Error code in IE is:

> Line: 28
>   Char: 3
>   Error: Invalid argument.
>   Code: 0

Line 28 is:

```
  var newWindow = window.open(theURL,winName,features+win_position);
```

Thanks for any help in solving this matter, I'm not a programmer at all and have no idea what I'm looking at, just copy and pasting and manipulating text to try and get stuff to work how I want.

Comment: Are you sure about the line number? The line number show by IE often doesn't correspond to the source. If you have a debugger, you can find where exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to MM_openBrWindow() only has two parameters, but it takes three. Try changing it to this:

```
MM_openBrWindow('images/festool/KAPEXKS120-571287/KAPEXKS120-571287-Gallery/','putsomenamehere','scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=840,height=580');
```

Comment: Doh! this is the issue, there is no window name.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but I recall having a problem with window.open in ie where the winName variable had a space in it. Maybe put an alert(winName) before it to check.

Comment: Quite likely...  IE will fail if the window name has spaces or tabs
http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/06/bug-289-popup-window-name-cant-have.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to watch the error in Firefox's javascript debugger:

> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216

Firefox often fails silently on javascript errors. So it might not be an IE only issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in your server-side code.  I'd look for the problem after the page is rendered.